# Changing state doesn't remove input values in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a table with different rows (react components). This rows are named service_users. When i click the save button of a row, a registerServiceUser method is called which updates the state in the parent component with a splice function. But after the state changes the input values from the saved row are passed to the next component (see screenshots).

The saved row is here the one with the name Milan den Vliet, after the save (which involves a state change) the value 23:00 and 1,00 are passed to the row of Finn de Dekker.

How can i prevent this behavior?

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Service user child component code:

```
return (
  <tr>
    <td style={tdStyle}>{driverIcon}</td>
    <td style={tdStyle}>{this.props.name}</td>
    <td style={tdStyle}>{moment(this.props.startTime).zone('00:00').format('HH:mm')}</td>
    <td><input type="text" onChange={this.handleEndTimeChange} className="form-control" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" onChange={this.handlePauseChange} className="form-control" defaultValue={this.state.pause_time} /></td>
    <td><input type="number" step="any" onChange={this.handleWorkHoursChange} className="form-control" value={this.state.work_hours} /></td>
    <td><input type="number" step="any" onChange={this.handleExtraHoursChange} className="form-control" placeholder="Extra uren"  style={extraHoursBackground} /></td>
    <td style={tdStyle}>{driverField}</td>
    <td style={tdStyle}><a href="#" onClick={this.registerTimesheet} className="btn btn-primary">Opslaan</a></td>
  </tr>
);
```

After save i update the state with this:

```
this.setState({ service_users: update(this.state.service_users, {$splice: [[index, 1]]}) });
```

Comment: Can you show some code? Also, are you directly applying splice to the state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you have a for-loop somewhere to generate the user rows. If this is the case, each row must have a unique key, preferably user ID or something similar. In that case

```
return (
    <tr>...</tr>
)
```

must be changed to

```
return (
    <tr key={this.props.id}>...</tr>
)
```

Unless you tell React to use a key, it just assumes that the top row is always the same, and just changes the values that have changed.

*Update: Take a look at this fiddle. It doesn't do the same thing as your app, but the concepts of changing state and removing the proper elements should apply nevertheless:* https://jsfiddle.net/jy0cgemz/

Comment: Ahh thanks for your answer! I was using unique id's for the key, but i used the index and when i remove an item, the index is passed to the next item. So i changed this to the id of the item, in my case service_user.id and now it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `key={i}` isn't really uniquely mapped to the user. It's just an index, and just cements your problem. On the first render, i = 0 for user Milan den Vliet and 1 for Finn de Dekker. On the second render, when Milan is removed, the first row is still i=0, and only then name has changed. The <tr> itself has the old state that belonged to Milan. Change `key={i}`to `key={user.id}` or name or whatever. Something uniquely attached to the user (row) object. Edit: Glad you figured it out :)